# How to retrieve which Button has been Clicked when Its Generated Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button, mvvm

Alright I am a C++ developer and currently I am working on WPF app and looks like this is a tricky situation. I have generated set of buttons, labels etc dynamically where both the textbox and button are bound to each other. I had done this in C++ code earlier and now I need to do it in WPF app.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox x:Name="myViewChannelList" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding VoltageCollection}" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" >
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <convert:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="booltovisibility"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Visibility="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource booltovisibility}}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170"  />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition  />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding ChannelName}" Margin="50,20,0,0"></Label>

                        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding VoltageText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="25" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="170,20,0,0" />
                            <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" Height="25" CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,20,0,0" ></Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
private ICommand m_voltageCommand;

    public ChannelList()
    {
         m_voltageCommand = new DelegateVoltageCommand(x => SetCommandExecute(x));
    }

public void Initialize()
{
    VoltageCollection = new ObservableCollection<VoltageModel> { new VoltageModel() { ChannelName = "", IsAvailable = false, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand },
                                                                 new VoltageModel() { ChannelName = "VDD__Main", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand }, 
                                                                 new VoltageModel() { ChannelName = "VDD__IO__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand }, 
                                                                 new VoltageModel() { ChannelName = "VDD__CODEC__AUD", IsAvailable = true, VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand } 
                                                               }; 
}

ObservableCollection<VoltageModel> _voltages;
public ObservableCollection<VoltageModel> VoltageCollection
{
    get
    {
        return _voltages;
    }
    set
    {
        _voltages = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("VoltageCollection");
    }
} 

// Event when SET Button is clicked
public void SetCommandExecute(object voltageText)
{       
    string value = voltageText.ToString();
    int val = Convert.ToInt32(value);
}
```

Thus it generates Button + Textbox + Label 3 times as shown in `Initialize()` method. Now `VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand` gives me the text entered in textbox and it calls `SetCommandExecute(object voltageText)` method where voltageText gives me the value entered.

**Model:**

```
string voltageText = string.Empty;
    public string VoltageText
    {
        get
        {
            return voltageText;
        }

        set
        {
            voltageText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("VoltageText");
        }
    }

**C++ Code:**

// Since we have 3 channels, channel maintains count
if(button == m_setButton[channel])
{
    unsigned cmd = 0x0300;
    int numBytes = 0;

    cmd |= (channel & 0xFF);
            // Some code
```

Here it tells the user which button has been clicked and takes the value of `channe`l i.e. if second button is clicked then `channel = 2`.

Here I need to implement the code as written in C++ one. How can I get the channel i.e. which button has been clicked. Have a look at `cmd |= (channel & 0xFF);`, it used the `channel` value. How can I achieve it in my app?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're looking to do, but why not pass the entire `VoltageModel` to the command instead of only passing the Text? Simply change `CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}"` to `CommandParameter="{Binding }"`

Comment: Why not just use the Tag property for the Button? `button1.Tag = 1`, etc.

Comment: @Bob: Tag property for dynamically generated button???? I have never come across dat

Comment: Dynamic or not, its a Framework Element property. :) I use custom classes for the Tag property for some of my code. [Tag property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) is one of many Framework Element properties that are really handly.

Comment: @Bob: Well have a look at the code first :) How can I get the tag? Elaborate using a code if you can mate :):)

Comment: @StonedJesus If you are using the MVVM design pattern, you really shouldn't be referencing UI objects at all. I don't understand why you want an actual reference to the `Button` object. It sounds like you just want to know the Item Index of item, in which case I would pass the `VoltageModel` as the `CommandParameter`, and use `VoltageCollection.IndexOf(ItemPassedInCommandParameter)` to find the index of the current item.

Comment: @Rachel: Yes i wanna know the index of button selected. I tried to set CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" in my xaml. And in SetCommandExecute() method I put VoltageCollection.Indexof(VoltageText) but it throws an error `VoltageText does not exist in this context`

Comment: @StonedJesus What is the data type of `VoltageText`? If you're passing in the entire `VoltageModel` as the `CommandParameter`, you should be casting the object in your `SetCommandExecute` as a `VoltageModel`, and not as a `string` or an `int`

Comment: @StonedJesus Understanding how to separate ViewModel from View was very difficult for me at first, as well. Listen to Rachel, she has saved my bacon on S.O.  many, many times. Once you get used to the VM being independant of the View (it will just "click" one day) all of this will be much, much easier. My question is: Why do you want to know the index of the button pressed? Whare are you going to do with that information?

Comment: @Rachel: Thanks for being patient :) Here `VoltageText` is of type `string` in My Model class. Since I am passing `VoltageModel` as `commandparameter`, how can I cast the object in `SetCommandExecute` as VoltageModel? :)

Comment: @StonedJesus I was about to answer your question, but see someone already posted it as an Answer below :)

Comment: @Rachel: yeah Mark helped me :) I appreciate your help too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add simply an ID Property to your VoltageBoardChannel Class.

```
int index ; 
public int ID 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return index; 
    } 

    set 
    { 
        index = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("ID"); 
    }
}
```

Then change your CommandParameter Binding to `CommandParameter="{Binding}"` instead of `CommandParameter="{Binding VoltageText}"` you will now receive not only the Text but also the instance of VoltageBoardChannel Class which now holds an ID.

**In your Command Executemethod**

```
public void DoSomethingExecute(object param) 
{ 
    VoltageBoardChannel result = param as VoltageBoardChannel; 
    string value = result.VoltageText;
    int index = result.ID;
}
```

Comment: THANKS MARK. I wish I could play a Drum Solo for you :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fundamental problem with your implimentation of MVVM:

*The ViewModel should never know about the View; It should be testable independant of any View elements*

In your SetCommandExecute method is expecting to do some work based text sent from the View. If you were to write a unit test for the SetCommandExecute method, using only information from other parts of the ViewModel, what would you pass in?

Instead, your SecCommandExecute should read:

```
SetCommandExecute(object voltageModel)
{
    VoltageModel myModel = voltageModel as VoltageModel; // Cast the model to the correct object type
    if (myModel != null)
    { // myModel will be null of voltageModel is not a VoltageModel instance
        // TODO: Whatever work you need to do based on the values of the myModel
    }
}
```

Your XML should read:

```
<Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Set" Height="25" CommandParameter="{Binding }" Command="{Binding VoltageCommand}" Width="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,20,0,0" ></Button>
```

How does this work? Well it comes down to the DataContext. Since your DataContext for each line in the grid is a VoltageModel, you are able to bind directly to several of its properties. Example `Text="{Binding VoltageText ...}"`

Each item in the datagrid has an implied DataContext of the object instance for each row. Since each row is binding to an instance of VoltageModel, then you can use that fact directly in your code. The View knows what ViewModel properties and instances it is working with, and can pass back "down" to the ViewModel the particular VoltageModel the user acted on.

Reasoning:

When your command event runs it should pass in the VoltageModel object, which gives you direct access to all of the instance properties. Remember that this is best practice because you want to be able to unit test the `SetCommandExecute` method without requiring that a view pass in some text, parsing it, finding some control on a View, and all that stuff.

In short: The ViewModel should be completely self-contained and able to run all unit test based on data available to just the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes I know. Rachel has helped me a lot earlier :) Well let me tell you what I wanna achieve here. When I enter value in textbox and click the button, the value entered is retrieved and calls the `SetCommandExecute` where object voltageText gives me the value entered. Thus here I will be performing some operations and I need to know which `channel` has been triggered i.e. if I enter value in `ChannelName="VDD_IO_AUD"` textbox and click SET button, it should gimme the index thats 2 since VDD_IO_AUD is the second item in list.

Comment: Using this value 2. I have to call updatemethod which does some operation :)

Comment: Just a clarifying question, each row has it's own set button, right?

Comment: yes buddy you are right :) For reference Check Initialize method. You will find `VoltageText = String.Empty, VoltageCommand = m_voltageCommand` Thus it gives me which the value I have entered in VoltageText and On Button Click takes the respective value :)

Answer (score 0):

I've only done a little WPF myself. When I bound my data to the control, there was some way for me to uniquely distinguish that data item from other data items.

pseudo code:

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  MyType obj = (MyType)listView1.SelectedItem[0];
  if (obj.UniqueItem == whatINeed) {
    DoStuffFunction();
  }
}
```

I don't know if that will work for your case, but that was how I tackled my problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate :) Looks like this is not gonna help me :(

Answer (score 0):

You're already binding the voltage text box to a property, so there shouldn't be a need to pass that value in as the command parameter.  Instead, you can specify the source as the Command:

```
<Button CommandParameter="TheButton" />
```

And in the implementation of your command handler:

```
public void SetCommandExecute(object source)
{       
    string source = source as string;

    if (source == "TheButton")
    {
       int val = Convert.ToInt32(this.VoltageText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done that already. Check the updated Code :) But still not able to figure out how to get it done

Comment: Hey brother, I am still not able to figure out what exactly you are tryin to do here :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Instead of Binding VoltageText to CommandParameter bind the Button to it and you can take VoltageText from ButtonDataContext or By Binding SelectedItem of ListBox to ViewModel Property.I hope this will help.

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button x:Name="btn" CommandParameter="btn" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30"/>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=lb}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="30"/> 
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    private ICommand _myCommand;
    public ICommand MyCommand { get { return _myCommand ?? (new CommandHandler((o) => FireCommand(o),()=> true)); } }
    public void FireCommand(object obj)
    {
        var a = lb.SelectedIndex; 
    }

public class CommandHandler:ICommand
{
        private Action<object> del;
        public CommandHandler(Action<object> action, Func<bool> b=null)
        {
            del = action;
        }

        #region ICommand Members

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            del(parameter);
        }

        #endregion
}
```

You can try with one of the above two ways .

Comment: Is ther any property of these buttons with which you can differentiate them?

Comment: Not really. I just wanna know the index of button selected.

Comment: I updated the answer. This is just kind of protoype to give the idea.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Two Buttons In ListBox?

Comment: Its just kind of demo each list Item having Button as of your each ListItem has button.